# how to concatenate a str and a float in python

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, concatenation

i have 2  pandas dataframes, one with the predictions of a neural net worked on tensorflow(i guess they are float) and the other with the names of every class(the string i supose), when i try this

```
predictions = model.predict_generator(pred_generator, steps=50)
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(labels,orient = 'index').index
y = pd.DataFrame(predictions[0])
print(pd.concat(x,y))
```

i get this error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

i was hopping you can helpme, in R it would be easier for me but i have not to much experience on python, thank you all in advance

Comment: if i delete the .index i get this error first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: I posted an answer to address both errors

Answer (score 2):

`x` isn't a dataframe because you used `.index` at the end.

Also, the error you get when you remove it is because both `x` and `y` have to be the first argument (in a list or tuple) to `concat`. Try this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(labels,orient = 'index')
y = pd.DataFrame(predictions[0])
print(pd.concat((x,y)))
```

Comment: hey man!  now the problem is that i get  
ADRIAN FRANCISCOESPINOZAORTEGA  0.000000e+00
ALEJANDROLOPEZTINOCO            1.000000e+00
ALFREDO CAMARILLO GARCIA        2.000000e+00
ANGEL FRANCISCOANDRADENEGRETE   3.000000e+00
ANGELBERMUDEZLOPEZ              4.000000e+00
...                                      ...
94                              2.521771e-06
95                              1.003536e-05
96                              3.682177e-08
the problem is that i want the name and the prob of the prediction df, can you helpme in this problem too?

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything without knowing what your data is and what output you want, post another question for that, your `concat` problem is solved

Comment: yeah thanks any way i solved whit this print(np.column_stack((x,y)))

Answer (score 0):

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(labels,orient = 'index')
y = pd.DataFrame(predictions[0])
print(np.column_stack((x,y)))
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).